# Sorting specific sections in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am using NSFetchedResultsController to populate the tableView of my application it is group by section(in which case a category property in my core data object) I want to reorder the section manually not by alphabet order.

below is the code of what I have done so far

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"Media" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                          initWithKey:@"category" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = 
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                    managedObjectContext:_context sectionNameKeyPath:@"category" 
                                               cacheName:@"Root"];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;    

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If the task is to provide the custom order of sections, than you can subclass NSFetchedResultsController and implement

```
- (NSInteger)sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)sectionIndex;
```

and, if needed

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *sectionIndexTitles;
- (NSString *)sectionIndexTitleForSectionName:(NSString *)sectionName;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new entity named `MediaCategory` with:

- an attribute `name`
- an attribute `rank`
- a to-many relationship `media` to the entity `Media`

and replace the `category` attribute with a relationship to `MediaCategory`.

Then, you can sort the request's result with the following sorts descriptors:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors =
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
 [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"category.rank" ascending:NO],
 [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"category.name" ascending:NO], // required only if many categories have the same rank
 nil];
```

and provide `@"category.name"` as the result controller's `sectionNameKeyPath`.